# Inform Account Team when new Opportunity added to account

Tags: account-teams

I want to be able to somehow inform the Account Team when a new opportunity is added. I don't mind if I do that by sending an email, or posting to chatter - what is the best option?
Tia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The new Lightning Process Builder can post to chatter](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=process_overview.htm&language=en_US) so you should be able to create a process that fires when an opportunity is created, but I don't know off the top of my head if you can email the entire team easily. One option there might be to create a group and automatically populate it with the team members, or even easier, just post to the Account assuming they all follow that record.

Keeping all of this kind of functionality in process builder (and moving it there from workflow etc.) is a good way to keep an eye on all of the automation (save for Apex) that's going on in your org.

Comment: Interesting, why do you say that Process Builder is better for monitoring than workflow?

Comment: Bad choice of words on my part, I don't mean for monitoring per se, but for knowing what automation is in place in an org. Right now we can spread things across triggers, processes, workflow rules and headless flow. Process builder is clearly the way the platform is headed on the declarative side and is very powerful, so it makes sense to keep things in once place to avoid confusion.

Comment: Agreed, but it is also still a risk for early adopters because of bulkification issues, etc. Regardless, it is the future and we definitely should encourage more people to use it.